# Can I configure gfortran-4.9 to mean gfortran in terminal?

Tags: terminal, gfortran

I'm having many problems installing packages where they have the default compiler as gfortran, and no master command to change it to gfortran-4.9

So I'd like to know if it's possible that whenever I type the gfortran command in the terminal, it interprets it to mean gfortran-4.9?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the alias command is used for exactly this.

I used alias gfortran="gfortran-4.9" in the terminal to get just that.

To get a permanent effect, I typed the command into ~/.bash_profile config file.